# Used memory in /proc/meminfo does not adds up

Tags: memory, linux-kernel

Looks at the output of `cat /proc/meminfo` I have MemTotal = 38GB, and Active + Inactive = 14 Gb. Cached is only 3GB

What is using most of my RAM on top of those 14GB of Active and Inactive ?
How does it reach the 31Gb of used Mem that `free` shows?

I would expect to have Memavailable of about 38-14-3 = 11 GB, instead Memavailable is 3.8GB

explanation of the output [Entry in /proc/meminfo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24484481/entry-in-proc-meminfo) and https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/6/html/deployment_guide/s2-proc-meminfo

```
> cat /proc/meminfo
MemTotal:       38109840 kB
MemFree:          955788 kB
MemAvailable:    3872636 kB
Buffers:          112176 kB
Cached:          3477880 kB
SwapCached:            0 kB
Active:         11723512 kB   = Active(anon) + Active(file)
Inactive:        2919292 kB   = Inactive(anon) + Inactive(file)
Active(anon):   11264332 kB
Inactive(anon):   159048 kB
Active(file):     459180 kB
Inactive(file):  2760244 kB
Unevictable:           0 kB
Mlocked:               0 kB
SwapTotal:             0 kB
SwapFree:              0 kB
Dirty:               580 kB
Writeback:             0 kB
AnonPages:      11053268 kB
Mapped:           321412 kB
Shmem:            370524 kB
Slab:             758444 kB
SReclaimable:     198992 kB
SUnreclaim:       559452 kB
KernelStack:       16608 kB
PageTables:        32104 kB
NFS_Unstable:          0 kB
Bounce:                0 kB
WritebackTmp:          0 kB
CommitLimit:    19054920 kB
Committed_AS:   13568652 kB
VmallocTotal:   34359738367 kB
VmallocUsed:           0 kB
VmallocChunk:          0 kB
HardwareCorrupted:     0 kB
AnonHugePages:         0 kB
ShmemHugePages:        0 kB
ShmemPmdMapped:        0 kB
HugePages_Total:       0
HugePages_Free:        0
HugePages_Rsvd:        0
HugePages_Surp:        0
Hugepagesize:       2048 kB
DirectMap4k:      159728 kB
DirectMap2M:    16617472 kB
DirectMap1G:    24117248 kB
```

I do have additional info

```
> free -mh
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:            36G         31G        1.7G        337M        3.6G        4.5G
Swap:            0B          0B          0B
```

```
> top

top - 16:14:09 up 23:43,  1 user,  load average: 14.65, 19.58, 18.87
Tasks: 266 total,   2 running, 263 sleeping,   1 stopped,   0 zombie
%Cpu(s): 36.2 us,  5.1 sy,  0.0 ni, 58.3 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.5 si,  0.0 st
KiB Mem : 38109840 total,   964388 free, 33356576 used,  3788876 buff/cache
KiB Swap:        0 total,        0 free,        0 used.  3881104 avail Mem
```

Comment: Why should they add up to anything?  They are all separate values tracked in the kernel.  See https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/420839/64699

Comment: I cannot attribute the 31GB of Used memory to anything at the moment, I was expecting something to adds up to that

Comment: `man free` explains that `used = total - free - buffers - cache`,  which in meminfo would be `used = MemTotal - MemFree - Buffers - Cached` which is 34G above, but I don't think you did `free -mh` at exactly the same time that you looked at `/proc/meminfo`

Comment: Actually, never mind.  They are the same.  free is in GiB, proc is in kib.